# How to execute a Java program automatically whenever Apache OFBiz startup?

Tags: java, ofbiz

We are using Apache ofbiz9.0 for our application. Now I want to execute a Java program automatically whenever ofbiz startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you starting OFBiz? Is it using the startOFBiz.bat?

You can easily write a bat file which will call these 2 lines

```
startOFBiz.bat
java MyClass.java
```